# How to Keep the first row at the top and only scroll the contents of the second row in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have 2 row in my grid like this:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinition>    
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now I want to when I scroll down, Keep the first row at the top and only scroll the contents of the second row.
How can I implement this?

Comment: i know that, but I put the frame in Scrollviewer So all the content will be scrollable, I no longer need to put a Scrollviewer for each page

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
       <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinition>    
  <ScrollViewer Grid.row = 1>
    //add content here ..
  </ScrollViewer> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="100">
        <!-- add content here .. -->
    </Grid>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <ScrollBar>
            <!-- add content here .. -->
        </ScrollBar>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have two grid definition. First grid with one row with scroll bar or view and second grid must have scrollbar or view.